# Multiple function call in one href tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flip

I'm developing one `Flipbook` by using `html`, `css`, `js`. Also, i have included video files with the Book. The problem with the book is, When i load the book for the first time, video file is working, after flipping Video is not working. I found what the problem is. It needs to be refreshed when each page turns.

The following is the code which i'm using to call the video file.

```
<a class="voverlay" id="sk" href="index_videolb/vdbplayer.swf?volume=100&url=video/change1.mp4" onclick="javascript:myfunc();"><img  src="index_videolb/thumbnails/change1.png"/></a>

<script>
  function myfunc()
  {
    location.reload(true);
  }
</script>
```

The problem with the code is, It only access the `Onclick` function, not `href`.

Is there anyother way to access both `href` and `onclick`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have both `href` and `onclick`, `href` would override any `onclick` behaviour. To avoid that you can do,

```
<script>
    function myfunc(event)
    {
       event.preventDefault();
       location.reload(true);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @Venkatesh No again same issue. reload function only working. When i click a button first process must be reload,then href. Is it possible? Or any other possible way?

Comment: When the page reloads, the javascript thread on the page is terminated. As a result, you cannot do it using Javascript. There are other hacky ways to do it using localStorage or other storage API's, but I suggest not to go with them.

Comment: `onclick` you should try to update the `href` of the anchor element. If that doesn't solve your problem, you should post a fiddle for better help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function myfunc() {                            
    window.location = "index_videolb/vdbplayer.swf?volume=100&url=video/change1.mp4";
}
```